# Windows 7 - Ran services.smc as administrator and it changed all status to "Manual" on reboot

Tags: windows-7, services, reboot

I disabled some services through `msconfig.exe`, when i start i.e. wamp it asks me for the service "wampapache" to be active and runing so i run `services.smc` and change the service status from **"Disabled"** to **"Manual"** and then start the service manually but when i close `services.smc` and re open it after a reboot the service "wampapache" went back to **"Disabled"** instead of **"Manual"**, so everytime i want to start the service instead of just making a script to run `sc start wampapache` i have to run `services.smc` change its status to **"Manual"** and then start it, so i figured i would start `services.smc` with **"run as administrator"** to see if this time when i change the service status to **"Manual"** it satys that way, and it worked but this time after i reboot i opened `services.smc`and it turns out all the status of every service that wasnt set as **"Automatic"** in the first place changed to **"Manual"**, all of them, **"Disabled"**, **"Automatic (delayed start)"**, etc.

Why did this happen?, how do i fix it?, how do i successfully change the status of some services to "Manual" and make it stay that way?

Thanks in advance this is a great community.

Comment: Have you checked the event log for the same.Please share the event information.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: start-run- eventvwr. It will open event viewer.